# Why is my 2D array only printing out one value?

Tags: c, arrays, 2d

I'm making a word search program and am in the beginning steps.  I'm trying to make user inputted sized grid of '+' before the user enters in the words that go into the word search.  When i run the program it only prints out one '+'.  Why is it only printing one value and how do i adjust my code so that every value is represented as '+'?  I'm a programming beginner so any advice would be helpful..thank you.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void printmatrix(char matrix[][20],int);

int main(void)
{
   char matrix[20][20]= {{'+'}};
   int x=1;

       printf("How large would you like the puzzle to be (between 10 and 20):\n");

   scanf("%d",&x);

   printmatrix(matrix,x);

   return 0;

}

/********************************************

 Function Name: Printmatrix...this function prints out an empty matrix of the grid size the user asked for

 Inputs: Variables x and y...the row and column variables the user inputted

 Outputs: Empty matrix filled with '+' thats the size the user asked for

********************************************/

void printmatrix(char matrix[][20],int x)
{
   int i,j;

   printf("Empty Puzzle:\n");

   for (i=0;i<x;i++)
   {
      for (j=0;j<x;j++)
      {
          printf("%c", matrix[i][j]);
      }
      printf("\n");
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you use a char array you can use memset to set the values of the array to the same value.

```
memset( matrix , '+' , sizeof( matrix ) ) ;
```

You code

```
char matrix[20][20]= {{'+'}};
```

will only do

```
matrix[0][0] = '+' ;
```

and the rest of array will be set to 0.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to write nested loops to init the matrix `char`s to '+':

```
char matrix[20][20];
int i;
int j;

/* Fill matrix with '+' */
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
        matrix[i][j] = '+';
    }
}
```

Comment: i had done this previously but in later steps in the program i have to use specific values from this matrix to insert words if that makes sense